# Inverse function of $1 / \log(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm attempting to transform an expression in 1/dB into linear units.

I use the following to transform between dB and linear units:

$f(x)[dB] = 10 \cdot \log(x)$

$\rightarrow f^{-1}(x) = 10^{\log(x)}$

Now I need to transform $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{10 \cdot \log(x)}$ but I can't find a way to do this, and every Google search ends up with an explanation of the inverse of $\log(x)$, and I can't find my notes on my math lectures. Anyone have an idea how to find the inverse function of $g(x)$?

Comment: The inverse of $\frac{1}{\log_b(x)}$ is $b^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: Danke, StiftungWarentest, that's actually quite useful (though it took me some attempts to understand how to implement the factor 10 in there, but alexjo already pointed that out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio of $P$ (measured power) to $P_0$ (reference power) is represented by $L_P$ expressed in decibels:

$$
L_{P}=10\log _{10}\!\left({\frac {P}{P_{0}}}\right)\,\quad{[\text{dB}}].
$$

Rearranging the above equation gives the following formula for $P$ in terms of $P_0$ and $L_P$:
$$
P=10^{\frac {L_{P}}{10\,{\text{dB}}}}\cdot P_{0}.
$$

So if you call $\frac {P}{P_{0}}=x$ and $L_P=f(x)$,
$$
x=10^{\frac {f(x)}{10\,{\text{dB}}}}
$$